# Can dynamic typing and dynamic scoping lead to each other?

Tags: programming-languages, dynamic-typing, scope

By definition, dynamic typing and dynamic scoping have different purposes. But some cases make me wonder if they can lead to each other sometimes.

1. Dynamic typing allows a name i.e. identifier to refer to objects of
   different types at different points at run time, e.g.

   ```
   x = 1
   x = 'abc'
   ```

   When dynamic typing changes the type of the object that a name
   refers to, does it lead to change of the scope of the name? In the
   above example, does the scope of the name `x` change when reaching
   the second assignment?
2. Dynamic scoping allows a name to refer to different objects at
   different points in run time. When the different objects that a name
   refers to have different types, does it lead to dynamic typing?

Thanks.

Comment: `Dynamic typing allows a name i.e. identifier to refer to objects of different types at different points at run time` -- Re-using a variable in this way is a really bad idea.  Just use a different variable with it's own (static or dynamic) type.

Comment: `Dynamic scoping allows a name to refer to different objects at different points in run time` -- This is a bad idea too.  In general, let your variables mean what they mean when you first declare them.  If you need to refer to something else, create a new variable specifically for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynamic scoping and dynamic typing have two things in common:

1. they have something to do with variables, and
2. they both contain the word “dynamic”.

What does “dynamic” mean here? Something is *dynamic* if changes with time.

With *dynamic typing*, the type of a variable may change with time. That means it is no longer meaningful to talk about *the* type of a *variable*. Instead, we should talk about the type of the *value* referenced by a variable. When we reassign a variable to a different value, we still have the same variable. Because it is the same variable, how the variable is scoped does not change.

With *dynamic scoping*, the visibility of a variable changes with time, or more precisely, with the control flow. Consider the following two functions:

```
func f() {
  print(x)
}

func g() {
  var x = 42
  f()
}
```

With *lexical scoping*, the variable `x` in the `f()` function will never refer to a value. Usually, a compiler would reject this program since `x` was never declared within a scope of `f()`.

With *dynamic scoping*, this depends on how `f()` was invoked. If we invoke `f()` directly, no `x` variable was assigned. If we invoke `g()`, a dynamically scoped `x` variable is assigned. This variable is then still visible during the execution of `f()`.

All of this is complicated and error prone. In fact, dynamic scoping is very similar to a global variable that's visible everywhere. In early programming languages (e.g. many Lisp dialects), dynamic scoping was more common since it's easier to implement that lexical scoping. However, it is avoided by more recent languages.

The only common programming languages I know which support dynamic scoping are *Perl* and *Bash*, both through the `local` keyword. The `local` keyword creates a new dynamic variable with the given name, which is destroyed when the lexical scope or the current function is left. Consider this Bash program:

```
print_x() { echo "$1: $x"; }
assign_x() { x="$1"; }

outer() {
  local x=a
  print_x outer #=> outer: a
  assign_x b
  print_x outer #=> outer: b
  inner
  print_x outer #=> outer: b
}

inner() {
  print_x inner #=> inner: b
  local x=1
  print_x inner #=> inner: 1
  assign_x 2
  print_x inner #=> inner: 2
}

outer
```

What happens here? The `print_x` and `assign_x` function will always access the current `x` variable. When `assign_x` assigns to `x`, it changes the current variable. The `outer` function creates an `x` variable, reassigns it through `assign_x`, then invokes the inner function. Here, we still have access to the current `x` from the `outer` function, before we create another `x` variable. Whatever we do to `x` now affects this new `x`, but leaves the old `x` alone. Only when we leave the `inner` function is the temporary `x` deleted, and the previous `x` becomes visible again.

This is important: there are two distinct `x` variables in this program. Changing (the type of) on variable does not affect the other.

If the effect of dynamic typing is needed in a language that does not support it, we must pass the data as function arguments instead. For the variable to be reassignable, we must pass it by reference, or as a pointer. However, dynamic scoping allows us to pass data through multiple function calls that do not include this parameter, so this is not a perfect solution.

Dynamic typing and dynamic scoping do not lead to each other. Dynamic scoping is rarely seen, and even less rarely without dynamic typing. However, there are many dynamically typed languages without dynamic scoping (e.g. Python), and even some languages with dynamic scoping but without dynamic typing (e.g. Bash: variables do have types, but it's complicated).

### Appendix: Dynamic scoping with static typing

There is a statically typed mainstream language with a feature similar to dynamic scoping: Java with its checked exceptions.

In a statically typed language, a function would have to declare the types of the dynamically scoped variables it uses, as they form a part of its interface. I'll now imagine a version of Java extended with dynamic scoping. A dynamic variable is declared with `implicit`. Every method has an optional `implicit`-specification clause, similar to a `throws`-specification. I will also assume this feature is somehow integrated with the generics system, and that sufficient type inference is available to not make this feature completely unwieldy.

The bash example would then translate:

```java
public class Main {
  private static void printX(String context) implicit Object x {
    System.out.println(context + ": " + x.toString());
  }

  private static <T> void assignX(T value) implicit T x {
    x = value;
  }

  private static outer() {
    implicit String x = "a";
    printX("outer");  //=> outer: a
    assignX("b");
    printX("outer"); //=> outer: b
    inner();
    printX("outer"); //=> outer: b
  }

  private static void inner() implicit Object x {
    printX("inner"); //=> inner: b
    implicit Integer x = 1;
    printX("inner"); //=> inner: 1
    assignX(2);
    printX("inner"): //=> inner: 2
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { outer(); }
}
```

As with checked exceptions, each method that calls a function with checked exceptions or with implicit variables must also declare those exceptions or implicit variables, which makes it more difficult to write generic functions. However, this is by no means impossible if the type system is sufficiently expressive. Assuming a C-style syntax for higher-order functions and generic parameters for implicit variables, we would have to express a `map` operation as

```
public static <type In, type Out, implicit... Implicits>
Out[] map(Out f(In x) implicit ...Implicits, In[] args) implicit ...Implicits {
  Out[] out = new Out[args.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    out[i] = f(args[i);
  return out;
}
```

where `f` could require any implicit variables. This requirement is then inherited by the `map` function. Note that part of the problem with checked exceptions in Java is that Java does not allow a similar forwarding of the `throws` declaration.

Comment: `Dynamic typing and dynamic scoping do not lead to each other. Dynamic scoping is rarely seen, and even less rarely without dynamic typing.` I'm really curious why you make this statement. It's clear that you can have dynamic typing without dynamic scoping but I don't see how you can have dynamic scoping without dynamic typing. Going back to your first example, the type of the variable `x` that function `f` sees depends on who called `f`.

Comment: @Doval with static typing, dynamic scoping would be much more verbose. Since the required dynamic variables are part of the function contract, these variables and their types would have to be declared similar to normal function parameters. The requirement to declare these means a function can not be transparent to dynamic scoping, and inherits the dynamic variable requirements of all functions it calls in turn. Sounds familar? It leads to the same mess as Java's checked exceptions. See my edit for an example of a hypothetical Implicit Variable Java.

Comment: In my mind that's no longer dynamic scoping, but now I'm just splitting hairs. Scala implements something like that with its [implicit parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html) but the caller doesn't necessarily have to have implicit parameters. I just wanted to make sure I didn't misunderstand. Thanks.

Comment: In the first example, `f` would have to require one specific type for `x` and a program will not typecheck unless there is a `x` variable with correct type, or we need a generics system so that `f` can handle `x` variables of many types.

Comment: Thanks. amon. Which books have you learned about programming language concepts? Which books would you recommend?

Comment: "The only common programming languages I know which support dynamic scoping are *Perl* and *Bash*" – Scheme introduced lexical scoping into the Lisp world, all Lisps before Scheme and some after it are dynamically scoped: Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp, newLisp, picoLisp. Also Logo, and most Shells, including PowerShell.

Comment: @Tim I learned most stuff by dabbling in many different languages, and trying to understand why these languages were designed that way. I've been able to learn much from in-depth resources specific to Perl or C++. Also, I sometimes write simple interpreters/projects to try out some concept (e.g. implementing OOP from scratch). For more general PL stuff, I've read some chapters of SICP (very good, but uses Lisp, and not really about PL) and “Types and Programming Languages” (academic textbook, still practical, do not read first), though I don't think any of those books discuss dynamic scoping.

Comment: amon, thanks. What resources to C++ did you learn about the concepts? I don't know much about Perl, but if possible, same question for Perl.

Comment: @Tim I just remembered there's a [MOOC on Programming Languages](https://www.coursera.org/learn/programming-languages) on Coursera – sign up, it's free. There are lots of video lectures about PL concepts. Classes with exercises start in 2 weeks, if you have the time. Highly recommended! When I looked at it 2 years ago I “dropped out” as the coursework is quite time-consuming, but I still learned *so much* from it. You will, too! Maybe I'll manage to fully participate this year.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. I also feel that participating in a course requires dedication of time to keep up with their pace. At least I will read the notes.